# How to re-deploy Django changes in linux

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, server, gunicorn

My application is up and running on my server. I'm using linux Nginx and Gunicorn.
I'm logging in to the server using ssh with private key.

My question is how do I re-deploy updated version of the application?

My first attempt was cloning the project from my git repository into a directory on my server. Cloning it again doesn't seem like a good option.

Comment: I run update from git, then python manage.py migrate, then systemctl restart web serwer and gunicorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pull your updates from your remote repository, then restart your gunicorn it will be updated immediately.

1. cd /project-path
2. git pull origin your-branch-name
3. Restart your gunicorn based on how are you running it.

You can automate this using any CI/CD like Gitlab CI.